# Why can't I connect to my windows 7 desktop through samba, but my laptop works fine?

Tags: windows-7, windows, samba, ubuntu-10.10

I'm setting up a home server, ubuntu 10.10, and trying to get file sharing working. I've installed samba, followed a guide, and it works partially. I can log into the shares on ubuntu fine, and ubuntu can access my laptop, but my desktop prompts for a non existent password. Both are running windows 7, with the same network settings which is why I'm confused. What could be the problem?

Comment: It would help to have more info about your network architecture and user logins, samba users, and to post somewhere the file smb.conf (please do not include the whole file in your post).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, don't use smbfs. Apparently it's deprecated and being eventually replaced with cifs. I found a tutorial on how to mount the shares using that and it worked.